# The meaning of error_code of mcontext_t in arm

Tags: c

We use the following code snippets to print the user context information in the handler registered via sigaction:

```
ucontext_t *p = (ucontext_t *)context;
fprintf(out, "pc %x\n", p->uc_mcontext.arm_pc);
fprintf(out, "fault addr %x\n", p->uc_mcontext.fault_address);
fprintf(out, "error %lu\n", p->uc_mcontext.error_code);
```

Does anyone know what is the meaning of `uc_mcontext.error_code`. Where can I find the list of possible error codes? Thanks.

Comment: `ucontext_t` is a struct that is either defined above somewhere in your code, or it is provided in a header file. Since you have direct access to its members, (e.g. `p->uc_mcontext.error_code` shows it is not an *opaque type*), you should be able to look the remainder of your code and find where `ucontext_t` is defined and look at what the `error_code` member is.

Comment: Yes, I can see it's defined as `unsigned long` in `struct sigcontext`, but what the value of it mean? Sometimes when the fault address is 0, the error code is 23. What the 23 means?

Comment: You will have to chase the `thread.error_code` down which is where your `uc_mcontext.error_code` is derived, e.g. `.error_code    = current->thread.error_code,` from `arch/arm/kernel/signal.c` (which I suspect draws from `errno.h`). You can start with [Commit 5ca451cf6ed04443774bbb7ee45332dafa42e99f](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/2/13/1501) and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Sometimes when the fault address is 0, the error code is 23. What the
>   23 means?"

If you start with the signal source for arm in [/arch/arm/kernel/signal.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/signal.h), you find the struct is defined in [/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/sigcontext.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/sigcontext.h)

And then you find `error_code` defined as an `unsigned long` in `struct sigcontext`, e.g.

```
struct sigcontext {
    unsigned long trap_no;
    unsigned long error_code;
    unsigned long oldmask;
    unsigned long arm_r0;
    unsigned long arm_r1;
    unsigned long arm_r2;
    unsigned long arm_r3;
    unsigned long arm_r4;
    unsigned long arm_r5;
    unsigned long arm_r6;
    unsigned long arm_r7;
    unsigned long arm_r8;
    unsigned long arm_r9;
    unsigned long arm_r10;
    unsigned long arm_fp;
    unsigned long arm_ip;
    unsigned long arm_sp;
    unsigned long arm_lr;
    unsigned long arm_pc;
    unsigned long arm_cpsr;
    unsigned long fault_address;
};
```

(**note:** the struct is different for `arm64`)

Then to find out what error number (`errno`) `23` is, you would start at [/arch/arm/kernel/signal.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/signal.c) and see that `linux/errno.h` is included and follow the trail to [/include/linux/errno.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/errno.h) which leads you to [/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h) and which finally leads you to [/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h)

```
#ifndef _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H
#define _ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H

#define EPERM        1  /* Operation not permitted */
...
#define ENFILE      23  /* File table overflow */
...
```

(**note:** the first 38 error codes are generic to all processes and architectures, though some cannot occur on specific architectures. Thus the reason they are found under the define `_ASM_GENERIC_ERRNO_BASE_H`)

Which you can then use any general reference to lookup like [man 3 errno](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) which would explain:

> ```
>    ENFILE          Too many open files in system (POSIX.1-2001).  On
>                    Linux, this is probably a result of encountering the
>                    /proc/sys/fs/file-max limit (see proc(5)).
> ```

You can also consult the `libc` [Error Codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html) documentation to find:

> ```
> Macro: int ENFILE
>
>     “Too many open files in system.” There are too many distinct file 
>     openings in the entire system. Note that any number of linked 
>     channels count as just one file opening; see Linked Channels. This 
>     error never occurs on GNU/Hurd systems.
> ```

Both of which point clearly to the problem being **"too many open files in system"**. Now it is up to you to find out why that is occurring in your code.

(**note:** as a shortcut you can simply search, e.g. `"linux error 23"` from which you would find the needed information at, e.g. [Errors: Linux System Errors](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html), but in not doing to reverse-trace, pay close attention to how old the file-location information is, as the `errno` could now be located at a completely different place in the tree than what is listed on older pages -- as is the case with the link above)

Comment: Wow, this is really a super detailed and useful information. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, hope it helps. It's not hard to do when you know where to start, but it is quite bewildering the first time. For big code bases like the Linux kernel there are usually a few good sites that provide the source online in a way you can either search or use the linked annotations to move around pretty quickly. Take a minute and look through a few. Good luck with your coding.